# How to get the PDF from the Cytoscape graph without blurring the image?

Tags: jspdf, cytoscape.js

I'm able to get the JPG and PNG images from the Cytoscape graph, but when converting them into PDF using jsPDF, the image shrinks and is blurry on zoom-in.

Is there a way the image or graph can be converted to PDF without blurring?

Comment: Can you include the code you're using?

Comment: // to get the jpg format of the cytoscape region 'cy'

var jpg64 = cy.jpg({
              full: true,
        quality: 1,
           });

Comment: As cytoscape not providing the pdf support, iam trying to make pdf of jpg using jspdf but the image is getting shrinked to the pdf size and also the image gets blurry if i zoom in (as the graph is so big)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you need to learn the difference between bitmap formats and vector formats.

Bitmap formats like PNG, GIF, BMP and JPEG *do not support* limitless zooming because they are made of small squares, called pixels.

Vector formats like PDF, SVG and EPS support limitless zooming without blurriness because they are made of geometrical shapes (though PDF can include bitmaps).

So you can convert between bitmap formats without problems (though you may get compression artifacts when using JPEG) but you cannot directly go from vector to bitmap and vice versa.

If you convert a vector image to bitmap, you need to rasterize it to a specific resolution.

If you convert a bitmap image to a vector image, you could use some advanced algorithms to guess the shape behind the pixels, but there is almost never enough information for this to work perfectly.

If you convert a bitmap image to PDF, the tool you are using may just embed the bitmap in the PDF. Now the PDF editor may let you zoom, but the image will get blurry.

The only way to get a real vector PDF is by having the application, in this case Cytoscape, export PDF directly, not converting it afterwards.

You wrote Cytoscape cannot do this but I am reading the manual of version 3.7.0 and it says you can export directly to PDF using "File → Export as Image..." and then selecting "PDF". Maybe at the time you posted this question, this version wasn't released yet.

P.S.: As noted by @ideogram you are using Cytoscape.js and not Cytoscape, so you can use the [cytoscape-svg NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cytoscape-svg) to export as SVG, which is a vector format, which you can then convert to PDF without getting any blurriness.

Comment: Is @CKA using Cytoscape or Cytoscape-js?